# Envoy Preserve Case Formatter using Istio

Tags: istio, envoyproxy

As per complaint of HTTP/1.1, Envoy is converting headers into lower-casing.

Rancher Version: 2.5.5
Istio Version: 1.5.9
Envoy Version: 1.13.4

Our case is, to keep the header as we requested like "Preserve Case".

I tried in Response level it's worked.

````
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: normalize-headers
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filter:
            name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
            subFilter:
              name: "envoy.router"
      patch:
        operation: MERGE
        value:
          typed_config:
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager"
            http_protocol_options:
              header_key_format:
                proper_case_words: {}```
````

I don't know how to change, what to change for response level.

Comment: Hi @pandiaraj. Could you give us an example? What is the current and expected behavior exactly?

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, When we send REST request to external systems, the headers are changing into lower-case, One of header named actionType changed in-to actiontype. Expected behaviour is istio or envoy proxy should not change the headers casing on both request and response headers. Above example is worked for response level like content-type: application/json into Content-Type: application/json. I want same behavior request headers as well.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor, we by-passed those ip's from envoy proxy.